# If the wraith could be "changed" but not instantly morally equivalent was it premature to call it a failure?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

Seeing as how the Wraith could...

> ...be changed back into humans wouldn't it have been better for the humans and the wraiths since they could eat normal food?

In the series, they claimed the change was a failure because the wraith turned humans didn't magically all of sudden have the same set of morals that humans today still deal with.

Don't humans go through years of moral and ethical education?

The difference and benefit though is that...

> ...they would no longer eat humans and some might show a conscience as a human.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that what you proposed was their original plan more or less. That the drug was wildly more successful than expected  and the side effect of wiping their memories was completely unexpected. So they basically tried to pull off a hail Mary and see if they could fully go back to human. That was a failure but was an impromptu long shot to begin with.

At the time they were in a position to be weighing the question you raised about whether to go back to their original plan, the wraith had already learned that they can feed on the converted wraiths. So providing the serum would have pretty much doomed anyone that took it to be food for other wraiths. At that point the moral question became a very different one than the one you presented. If the wraith didn't find out about the serums use as a weapon, I think the Atlantis team would have looked into ways of at least providing it to wraiths as an option.

Comment: FWIW, wraith can also feed on other wraith if they have to. (Season 1 Episode 12 The Defiant One demonstrates this during a long term survival situation.) Doesn't change this answer really, but only noting for clarification since "the wraith ... can feed on the converted wraiths" could be misinterpreted as the only way they can feed on their own kind, which isn't the case.